# Optimizing random cards assignment

Tags: python, random

I have a deck of 21 cards and 6 players. I will label each card with a letter from the alphabet. 
I have to randomly assign 3 cards to each player (for a total of 18 cards, 3 are left in the deck) under some conditions, which are divided in two different categories:

- `andlist(x) = [[g, e, h],[k, m, f]]`, which means: *'g, e, h, k, m, f cannot be assigned to player x'*
- `orlist(x) = [[a, l, i], [j, d ,o], [b, n, c]]`, which means: *'a or l or i, and j or d or o, and b or n or c must be assigned to player x'*.

Of course this is just an example; `andlist(x)` and `orlist(x)` can contain different numbers of nested triplets for each player.

I wrote a simple code that keeps assigning the 18 cards to the 6 players completely random, until the conditions are met (using a `while` loop), but this strategy is very unefficient as it takes too long to find an appropriate allocation.

Is there any more efficient way to deal with this kind of conditions in Python?

Comment: Show the simple code you've written so far, please.

Comment: Could you also show a larger example of `andlist` and `orlist`? (Also, is this for some real-life game? Would help to see concrete rules, etc.)

Comment: As AKX mentioned including what you have done would be a good start for people to be able to help you. Conceptually you can think of your problem as a process. Random process until conditions are met is your current solution = brute force. You can think of your 'conditions' as a restriction to what cards that a player can get. The hint is in the naming -> 'and' and 'or'. I would suggest devising a random picking operation that take into account the additional 'rules' for each player.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like an interesting snack – I'm sure a constraint solver or something would work better, but here's something based on the idea that `orlist` defines certain base cases we can iterate off of, recursing a tree of possible solutions until we reach a working one. (As an afterthought, this actually doesn't recurse through the full tree of possible hand combinations since `generate_new_solution` is itself not a recursive generator...)

It, of course, also could be buggy.

```
import random
import string
import itertools
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_
from typing import Iterable, Dict

deck_size = 21
player_count = 6
hand_size = 3

card_names = set(string.ascii_lowercase[i] for i in range(deck_size))

forbidden_cards = {
    0: [set("geh"), set("kmf")],
}

required_sets = {
    # 'a or l or i, and j or d or o, and b or n or c must be assigned to player x'.
    0: [set("ali"), set("jdo"), set("bnc")],
    1: [set("geh")],
    2: [set("kmf")],
}

# Flatten the forbidden card dict sets for faster iteration

flat_forbidden_cards = {idx: frozenset(reduce(or_, forbidden_cards.get(idx, ()), set())) for idx in range(player_count)}


def is_solution_forbidden(solution: Dict[int, frozenset]) -> bool:
    """
    Figure out if the solution is forbidden, i.e. any player has a forbidden card
    """
    for idx, cards in solution.items():
        if cards & flat_forbidden_cards.get(idx):
            return True
    return False


def is_solution_finished(solution: Dict[int, frozenset]) -> bool:
    """
    Figure out if the solution is finished, i.e. all players have been dealt hand_size cards.
    """
    return all(len(hand) == hand_size for hand in solution.values())


def get_root_solutions() -> Iterable[Dict[int, frozenset]]:
    """
    Generate "root" solutions that satisfy the "required sets" constraints.
    """
    required_roots = {
        idx: [frozenset(card_ids) for card_ids in itertools.product(*required_sets.get(idx, ()))]
        for idx in range(player_count)
    }
    for base_sol_cards in itertools.product(*required_roots.values()):
        yield {i: cards for i, cards in enumerate(base_sol_cards)}


def iterate_solutions(base_solution: Dict[int, frozenset]) -> Iterable[Dict[int, frozenset]]:
    """
    Recursive generator for solutions based on `base_solution`.

    Only ever yields finished solutions.
    """
    new_sol = generate_new_solution(base_solution)
    if is_solution_finished(new_sol):
        yield new_sol
    else:
        yield from iterate_solutions(new_sol)


def generate_new_solution(base_solution: Dict[int, frozenset]):
    used_cards = reduce(or_, base_solution.values())
    available_cards = card_names - used_cards
    deal = {}
    for idx in range(player_count):
        if len(base_solution[idx]) < hand_size:
            allowed_player_cards = available_cards - set(deal.values()) - flat_forbidden_cards[idx]
            if not allowed_player_cards:
                raise RuntimeError("Ran out of cards to pick")
            deal[idx] = random.choice(list(allowed_player_cards))
    new_sol = base_solution.copy()
    for idx, hand in base_solution.items():
        if idx in deal:
            new_sol[idx] = frozenset(hand | {deal[idx]})
    assert not is_solution_forbidden(new_sol)
    return new_sol


for root_sol in get_root_solutions():
    assert not is_solution_forbidden(root_sol)  # Should never happen, good to check though
    for solution in iterate_solutions(root_sol):
        print({idx: "".join(sorted(hand)) for idx, hand in solution.items()})
```

The output is something like this (though in reality there are 243 lines, not 6), dicts describing the cards in each player's hands.

```
{0: 'bdi', 1: 'hmu', 2: 'efq', 3: 'apt', 4: 'cko', 5: 'jns'}
{0: 'bjl', 1: 'eno', 2: 'ikm', 3: 'hqs', 4: 'adg', 5: 'frt'}
{0: 'abd', 1: 'glm', 2: 'fjn', 3: 'ior', 4: 'hps', 5: 'equ'}
{0: 'bio', 1: 'hmp', 2: 'fjl', 3: 'aeu', 4: 'drt', 5: 'kns'}
{0: 'blo', 1: 'agh', 2: 'fru', 3: 'mnp', 4: 'des', 5: 'cqt'}
```